# Properly uninstall Anything Sync Daemon

Tags: software-installation

I tried Anything Sync Daemon on my Raspberry, but it doesn't work reliable with /var/log folder. 
Now I have stoped and disable service. 
How should I properly uninstall everything connected with this?

EDIT: I used this steps for install: http://raspberryserver.blogspot.si/2016/08/

Comment: read the end of the makefile  .... https://github.com/graysky2/anything-sync-daemon/blob/master/Makefile

Comment: Tnx, I will check.

Comment: `it doesn't work reliable with /var/log folder` ... what does this mean?

Comment: Some logs aren't updated (when the should be), some are. And strange folders apears ... after that I read this support forum where /var/log is mentioned as not recommended. But this was my main idea :-)